# param is missing or the value is empty:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here is booking controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create]

    def new
        @booking = Booking.new
    end

    def index
        @bookings = Booking.all
    end

    def create
        @booking = current_user.bookings.build(booking_params)
        if @booking.save
            flash[:success] = "Booking created!"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
          render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end


    def show
        @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
        @booking.destroy
        redirect_to bookings_path
    end

    private
        def booking_params
            params.require(:booking).permit(:date, :hour, :game)
        end   
end
```

When I post after the utf8 and authenticity token I don't understand why "#<\Booking:0x000001061928a8>\" instead of simply "booking" then the nested hash contains date, hour and game which I permit in the controller.

Here is the view:

```
<%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :day %>
    <%= date_field(@booking, :date) %>

    <%= f.label :hour %>
    <%= number_field(@booking, :hour, in: 8..19) %>

    <%= f.label :game %>
    <%= select(@booking, :game, [['Singles', 1], ['Doubles', 2]]) %>

  <%= f.submit "Book", class: "btn btn-primary" %>    
<% end %>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I wanted to include the posted parameters but it wouldn't accept it here either as code or as text. The backslash is to escape the greater than and less than characters in the booking token.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem/issue. Can you explain in more detail? Getting a <\Booking:0x000001061928a8>\" object is what you would expect from a create action so I must be missing something.

Comment: Hi Richard,so do I think the parameters are correct and this is why I'm at odds to eliminate the "param is missing or the value is empty: booking", as I'm new to Rails wasn't sure of hash in front of booking and don't know how the hexadecimal number is generated

Comment: I can't see what's wrong I've not had the problem posting with other simple forms only difference here is I'm using select boxes instead of text fields and an association where bookings belong to users. The error is raised on line: params.require(:booking).permit(:date, :hour, :game) so I guess it's not permitting the parameters corresponding to the form. I'd changed first parameter from day to date to no avail.

Comment: Didn't manage to edit in time after "so I guess.." I'll try to be clearer I think the error comes from date_field, the posted parameter is: "date"=>"2015-04-25" but bookings table column is "day" date being reserved type of course. I'd changed day to date in the form and controller but that introduced an extra error, I'd forgotten object attributes are implicit from db.

Answer (score 2):

Ok it was simply that I wasn't using the the f variable of the form builder for the select boxes, originally I was but I'd had problems rendering the select boxes so I'd taken it out. Must have been due to a syntax error.
Here's the working form_for with a date picker and other select boxes:

```
<div class="field">
<%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :day %>
    <%= f.date_field :day %>

    <%= f.label :hour %>
    <%= f.number_field :hour, in: 8..19 %>

    <%= f.label :game %>
    <%= f.select :game, [['Singles', 1], ['Doubles', 2]] %>

  <%= f.submit "Book", class: "btn btn-primary" %>    
<% end %>

</div>
```